# How to set gpg2 as default implementation of gpg on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, gnupg, default-settings

My debian installation came with gpg 1.4.12, while I would like to be running 2.0.19.
The former comes in the package `gnupg` and the latter `gnupg2`. They can coexist peacefully as far as I know, but I would really like to use `gpg2` as the default provider of `gpg`. I know debian has `update-alternatives` which is used for setting defaults, but I can't find any mention of `gpg` or `gnupg` in it.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 13):

## Answer

`update-alternatives` only works if a package explicitly uses the alternatives system. gnupg and gnupg2 don't.

## Background

Usually the reason is that the user-interface differs too much so that scripts using the one tool won't work anymore if suddenly the other tools runs instead. A typical example here is `markdown`. Each `markdown` implementation in Debian has quite different commandline options, hence the alternatives system is not in use there.

`gpg`'s and `gpg2`'s commandline options don't seem to differ much, but maybe the output on certain actions or exit codes differ significantly at some places.

One thing where they differ and which is important for minimal installations and installation media, are their dependencies. While the `gnupg` package is of priority "standard" (i.e. installed in a standard installation) and a dependency of the package `apt`, the package `gnupg2` pulls in quite some more libraries which are currently only of priority "optional".

There are two open bug reports in Debian, one against each package ([#561540 against gnupg](https://bugs.debian.org/561540) and [#483724 against gnupg2](https://bugs.debian.org/483724)), requesting the use of the alternatives system for `gnupg` and `gnupg2`.

Currently one of these bug reports is tagged `wontfix`, but the tag is said to be "for now" and there are [some hints what needs to be taken care of](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=561540#49) in case the alternatives system will be used (or `gnupg2` will become the default) in the future.

## How To, In Case You Really Want

If you really want `gpg2` to be called if you called `gpg`, I recommend to add an according alias in your shell, e.g. with `alias gpg=gpg2` for bourne-shell compatible shells. Shouldn't do much harm, but will only work if called from the commandline.

If you really want to have `/usr/bin/gpg` to be gnupg2, you can do that with `dpkg-divert`, e.g. rename `gpg` to `gpg1` and then `gpg2` to `gpg`. Files renamed with `dpkg-divert` will keep their new name even after updates of the according packages.

**But be warned:** APT requires and uses `gpg` and may not expect it to actually be `gpg2`. So you may break parts of your system if you use `dpkg-divert` that way. (Shell aliases for non-root users are fine with regards to that.)

Answer (score 7):

There will be a new answer to that question very soon: Use Debian 9 Stretch (to be released in like 2 years or so ;-) or newer.

Background: At [DebConf15](http://debconf15.debconf.org/) the Debian GnuPG Package Maintainers [announced](https://summit.debconf.org/debconf15/meeting/195/gnupg-in-debian-report/) that in the future, GnuPG 2.x will be `/usr/bin/gpg` in Debian and the GnuPG 1.x command will be renamed to `/usr/bin/gpg1`.

You still won't be able to switch `/usr/bin/gpg` to another GnuPG version to your likes (see my other answer for the reason behind this), but at least GnuPG 2.x will be the default implementation in the near future in Debian Unstable and Debian Testing and very soon in Debian Experimental.

Comment: Side note, 2017-06-14: debian tools in the latest stable version still use hardcoded gpg1 internally. Debian forks (ubuntu, mint) seem to fix it.

Comment: Side note, 2017-06-17: debian tools in the latest stable version use gpg2. (Yes, I can see into the future. ;-) Just kidding, but @peterh wrote that comment just like three days before the next Debian Stable release will be released which changes exactly that.

Comment: Good, thanks! However, digging into the gpg2 has teached pretty well to me, why were you so slow to upgrade the gpg versions. I think the real cause of the problem is the gpg. I think, maybe a project fork seems needed, how about it? If somebody would simply open a gpg2 fork on the github, and fix all of its braindamages, how would it be received? I am thinking on to do it, but it simply doesn't worth its price if it remains a forgotten archive forever.