# Use gpg2 as gpg replacement OSX

Tags: macos, gnupg

I installed the `gnupg2` formula from Homebrew successfully and can run `gpg2` from the command line. However, certain programs such as `git` expect to run `gpg` rather than `gpg2`.

I resolved this problem by using what I feel like is a dirty hack: a symlink of `gpg2` to `gpg`:

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/gpg2 /usr/local/bin/gpg`

Is there a more proper way to do this? Should I just settle for installing the `gnupg` formula?

Sort of looking for something like this for OSX: [How to set gpg2 as default implementation of gpg on debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/763724/how-to-set-gpg2-as-default-implementation-of-gpg-on-debian).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Be aware that GnuPG 2 sometimes has slightly different ouput, especially with GnuPG 2.1. This will usually not be a problem, but in rare cases weird things might happen.

Individually configure the `gpg` binary to be used per application. For example, git has the `gpg.program` option. From `man gpg-config`:

```
gpg.program

Use this custom program instead of "gpg" found on $PATH when making or verifying
a PGP signature. The program must support the same command-line interface as
GPG, namely, to verify a detached signature, "gpg --verify $file - <$signature"
is run, and the program is expected to signal a good signature by exiting with
code 0, and to generate an ascii-armored detached signature, the standard input
of "gpg -bsau $key" is fed with the contents to be signed, and the program is
expected to send the result to its standard output.
```

Use `git config --global gpg.program gpg2` to choose GnuPG 2 for your user, or replace `--global` with `--system` to change the setting for all users.

Comment: Works perfectly for git! Thanks. Do you know an easy way to get zsh completion for gpg2?

Comment: I'm using bash only, I cannot help you with that. But this seems to be an excellent additional question to ask. I'd consider going to the [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange though, I guess you will find more people familiar with zsh over there than here on Super User. Don't be scared of mentioning OS X there (if sticking to the command line), in the end it's just another Unix system.

Comment: Thank you for your help! For reference I asked the question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188945/zsh-gpg2-autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the symlink maybe you can try this?

```
brew link --overwrite gnupg
```