# Why does git complain that no GPG agent is running?

Tags: windows, git, gnupg

I have the `gpg-agent.exe` running, but when I try to `git commit`, it complains that the GPG agent can not be found:

```
$ gpg-agent --daemon
gpg-agent[17440]: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

$ git commit -m "foo"

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Oliver Salzburg <oliver.salzburg@gmail.com>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID 5826006B, created 2016-12-05

gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
Enter passphrase:
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is likely that your `gpg-agent` and `gpg` binaries are from different packages.

This can happen when you're using **Git Bash** (which ships with `gpg`) and you're installing **GnuPG4Win** additionally. The latter ships with a more recent version.

You can [verfiy if this is your problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231386/how-to-make-gpg-find-gpg-agent), by checking the version of both programs:

```
% gpg-agent --version
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.7

% gpg --version                                                               
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.19
```

If this is your problem, you should [tell `git` which `gpg` binary to use](https://superuser.com/questions/887110/use-gpg2-as-gpg-replacement-osx):

```
% git config --global gpg.program gpg2
```

Comment: Current versions of gpg4win do not call the gpg executable `gpg2` anymore, so git now requires the full path to the executable (with forward slashes).

Answer (score 36):

When this message is issued upon commiting:

> gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: IPC connect call failed
> gpg: keydb_search failed: No agent running

The following command starts the gpg-agent on Windows:

`gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`

After reloading the agent the signing password prompt is displayed properly.

**Environment**
Windows 11 Home 21H2
git version 2.32.0.windows.2
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.1
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.3.1

Comment: This answer perfectly solved for me, where I have matching `gpg-agent` and `gpg` but the agent is refusing to load.

Answer (score 3):

This should work on Windows 11, mind that I have installed GnuPG, which causes the bug (probably) in the first place.

```
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
```

For me this also fixed the Bug, that git-towers had a problem connecting to the service.

PS: Worked for me in Windows PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others said you should also check your `.gitconfig` file. In my case I just needed to add quotes to the executable path:
[screenshot of gpg section on .gitconfig file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8e3z.png)

```
[gpg]
# program = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg.exe
program = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg.exe"
```

---

I got this error when trying to sign commits for the first time after reeboting and was able to reproduce it by killing `gpg`, `gpg-agent`, and `git` processes.
Apparently it didn't catch that setting at first and relied on what was installed on `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.