# Generate GPG key on Windows 10 gives error message

Tags: windows, gnupg, gpg-agent

```
gpg --generate-key
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
Key generation failed: No agent running
```

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46673717/2422776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does git complain that no GPG agent is running?](https://superuser.com/questions/1153101/why-does-git-complain-that-no-gpg-agent-is-running)